# CSS animation, fade in fade out opacity on automated slideshow

Tags: html, css, animation, fading

I want to make a slideshow where the pictures transition through fade in fade out opacity. it just glooms on the screen and switches to the next picture.

I got it to work but added the other brower webkits and it stopped working. Can't seem to find my mistake.. The slideshow still works.

This is the code:

```
/* Fading animation in css */
.fade {
-webkit-animation-name: fade 5s;
animation-name: fade 5s;
-moz-animation: fade 5s;
-o-animation: fade 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
0% {opacity: 0.2} 
50% {opacity: 1}
100% {opacity:0.2}
}

@-moz-keyframes fade{
    0% {opacity: 0.2} 
  50% {opacity: 1}
  100% {opacity:0}  
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {opacity: 0.2} 
  50% {opacity: 1}
  100%{opacity: 0.2}
    }
@-o-keyframes fade {
0% {opacity: 0.2} 
  50% {opacity: 1}
  100%{opacity: 0.2}

}

<div class="slideshowcontainer">
        <div class="slideshow fade">
            <img src="images/PSA.PNG">
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow fade">
            <img src="images/OWSA.PNG">
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow fade">
            <img src="images/CEAC.PNG">
        </div>
```

Comment: not sure if it solves your problem, but in the code you posted above, you are missing a closing div tag, </div> at the end.

Comment: Ah forgot to copy that one, mb, the answer is the first one below, helped me out

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just modify the `.fade` class to this

```
.fade {
  -webkit-animation: fade 5s;
  animation: fade 5s;
  -moz-animation: fade 5s;
  -o-animation: fade 5s;
}
```

Because `animation-name` does not expect a timeinterval, it only expects the name.

```css
.fade {
-webkit-animation: fade 5s;
animation: fade 5s;
-moz-animation: fade 5s;
-o-animation: fade 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
0% {opacity: 0.2} 
50% {opacity: 1}
100% {opacity:0.2}
}

@-moz-keyframes fade{
    0% {opacity: 0.2} 
  50% {opacity: 1}
  100% {opacity:0}  
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {opacity: 0.2} 
  50% {opacity: 1}
  100%{opacity: 0.2}
    }
@-o-keyframes fade {
0% {opacity: 0.2} 
  50% {opacity: 1}
  100%{opacity: 0.2}

}
```

```html
<div class="slideshowcontainer">
        <div class="slideshow fade">
            <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71%2BmEwFaoaL._SL1500_.jpg" width="200px" height: "200px">
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Kindly help on this one pls? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61203327/css-animation-fadein-fadeout-2-images-continuously

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was looking a solution for a one shot transition for use with blazor.

Answer (score 5):

you just need to change the property name

from

```
.fade {
-webkit-animation-name: fade 5s;
animation-name: fade 5s;
-moz-animation: fade 5s;
-o-animation: fade 5s;
}
```

to

```
.fade {
-webkit-animation: fade 5s;
animation: fade 5s;
-moz-animation: fade 5s;
-o-animation: fade 5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`animation-name` wont take seconds, only the name. change `animation-name` to just `animation`.